# What is the Jyotistoma Yajna?

Tags: yajna

In the Siddhanta Siromani Vasanabhasya we have reference to atleast three important Yajnas - "... दर्शपौर्णमासयागज्योतिष्टोमादयः ..." that is, the Yajnas performed at the new moon and full moon , and the Jyotishtoma Yajna. So what were these about and how were they performed?

Comment: There are many types of soma yagnas like अग्निष्टोमा, आयुष्टोम, अत्यग्निष्तोम, Jyotishtoma also refers to one such 
https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/jyotishtoma